How to make cdk keep previous lambda version using python?
I have this code for my stack:
from aws_cdk import CfnOutput, Duration, RemovalPolicy, Size, Stack
from aws_cdk import aws_iam as iam
from aws_cdk import aws_lambda as _lambda
from constructs import Construct


class VsConverterStack(Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, stage: str, **kwargs) -> None:  # type: ignore
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        s3_buckets = {
            "test": {"full": "arn:aws:s3:::mgq-data-test", "name": "mgq-data-test"},
            "beta": {"full": "arn:aws:s3:::mgq-data-beta", "name": "mgq-data-beta"},
            "prod": {"full": "arn:aws:s3:::mgq-data-prod", "name": "mgq-data-prod"},
        }

        if stage not in s3_buckets:
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid stage: {stage}. Must be 'test', 'beta' or 'prod'.")

        # Define Docker image for Lambda using the Dockerfile from the repo root
        docker_image = _lambda.DockerImageCode.from_image_asset(
            directory="../"  # Path to your Dockerfile directory
        )

        # Define the Lambda function with the Docker image
        vs_convert_function = _lambda.DockerImageFunction(
            self,
            "converter",
            function_name=f"vs-converter-{stage}",
            code=docker_image,
            timeout=Duration.seconds(900),
            memory_size=10240,
            ephemeral_storage_size=Size.gibibytes(1),
            environment={"BUCKET": s3_buckets[stage]["name"]},
        )

        # Create a version based on the function's current state
        version = _lambda.Version(
            self,
            "ConverterVersion",
            lambda_=vs_convert_function,
            # removal_policy=RemovalPolicy.RETAIN,
        )

        # Create an alias pointing to the new version
        vs_convert_function_alias = _lambda.Alias(self, "ConverterAlias", alias_name="current", version=version)

        # IAM permissions for the S3 bucket
        bucket_policy = iam.PolicyStatement(
            effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            actions=[
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
            ],
            resources=[f"{s3_buckets[stage]['full']}", f"{s3_buckets[stage]['full']}/*"],
        )
        vs_convert_function.add_to_role_policy(bucket_policy)

        # Add CfnOutput to display the Lambda function name and version
        CfnOutput(self, "LambdaFunctionName", value=vs_convert_function.function_name)
        CfnOutput(self, "LambdaVersion", value=version.version)
        CfnOutput(self, "LambdaAlias", value=vs_convert_function_alias.alias_name)

No matter what I change in my python codebase or in the Dockerfile, whenever I do code deploy I get the same version number, even when cdk diff shows differences.
I'm coming from Serverless Framework and I'm finding challenging to figure out in CDK things that are natural in Serverless.

I realised I was using removal_policy=RemovalPolicy.RETAIN, in the wrong place
from aws_cdk import CfnOutput, Duration, RemovalPolicy, Size, Stack
from aws_cdk import aws_iam as iam
from aws_cdk import aws_lambda as _lambda
from constructs import Construct


class VsConverterStack(Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, stage: str, **kwargs) -> None:  # type: ignore
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        s3_buckets = {
            "test": {"full": "arn:aws:s3:::mgq-data-test", "name": "mgq-data-test"},
            "beta": {"full": "arn:aws:s3:::mgq-data-beta", "name": "mgq-data-beta"},
            "prod": {"full": "arn:aws:s3:::mgq-data-prod", "name": "mgq-data-prod"},
        }

        if stage not in s3_buckets:
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid stage: {stage}. Must be 'test', 'beta' or 'prod'.")

        # Define Docker image for Lambda using the Dockerfile from the repo root
        docker_image = _lambda.DockerImageCode.from_image_asset(
            directory="../"  # Path to your Dockerfile directory
        )

        # Define the Lambda function with the Docker image
        vs_convert_function = _lambda.DockerImageFunction(
            self,
            "converter",
            function_name=f"vs-converter-{stage}",
            code=docker_image,
            timeout=Duration.seconds(900),
            memory_size=10240,
            ephemeral_storage_size=Size.gibibytes(1),
            environment={"BUCKET": s3_buckets[stage]["name"]},
            current_version_options={"removal_policy": RemovalPolicy.RETAIN}, # <-- correct way
        )

        # Publish a new version
        version = vs_convert_function.current_version

        # Create an alias pointing to the latest version
        vs_convert_function_alias = _lambda.Alias(self, "ConverterAlias", alias_name="current", version=version)

        # IAM permissions for the S3 bucket
        bucket_policy = iam.PolicyStatement(
            effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            actions=[
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
            ],
            resources=[f"{s3_buckets[stage]['full']}", f"{s3_buckets[stage]['full']}/*"],
        )
        vs_convert_function.add_to_role_policy(bucket_policy)

        # Add CfnOutput to display the Lambda function name and version
        CfnOutput(self, "LambdaFunctionName", value=vs_convert_function.function_name)
        CfnOutput(self, "LambdaVersion", value=version.version)
        CfnOutput(self, "LambdaAlias", value=vs_convert_function_alias.alias_name)

